# Before Insert trigger setting one column = to another column based on IF Statement

Tags: mysql

On an insert if a column does not have a value entered 
its value will be null

If its NULL I want to set the value of the column to
another column in the insert record

On an Insert trigger on use the code

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 
`infrastructure`.`Wall_Drop_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Wall_Drop` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

If new.drop_label = null then 
set new.drop_label = new.Drop_id;
end if;

END
```

The value is not updated, it still has the value null after
the update

Comment: `IS NULL`, not `= null`

Comment: Or `new.drop_label <=> null`

Answer (score 3):

A comparison with `NULL` (like `new.drop_label = null`) will always be evaluated as `NULL`. Thus can never be `TRUE`. You need to use either

```
If new.drop_label is null
```

Or the NULL-save opreator

```
If new.drop_label <=> null
```

Read more about "Working with NULL Values" in [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).

However - What you want, can also be done in one step using `COALESCE()`:

```
BEGIN

set new.drop_label = coalesce(new.drop_label, new.Drop_id);

END
```

Comment: # set value of drop_labes if not entered    
If new.drop_label is null then
set new.drop_label = new.drop_id;


If new.drop_label <=> null then
set new.drop_label = new.drop_id;

Set new.drop_label = coalesce(new.drop_label, new.Drop_id);